# Angular2 pass directive in Subchild

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I build a simple List UI component, which contains items, which are also components:

`AppComponent -> ListComponent -> ListItemComponent`

I want this list to visualize different types of list item components.

For example 2 types of list items:

```js
 @Component({
   selector: 'list-item',
   template: 'This is a PRODUCT!'
 })
 export class ProductListItemComponent { }
```

```js
 @Component({
   selector: 'list-item',
   template: 'This is a PERSON!'
 })
 export class PersonListItemComponent { }
```

So, when I initialize my app component:

```js
 import {ListComponent} from '...';
 import {ProductListItemComponent} from '...';

 @Component({
   selector: 'list-item',
   template: `
     <list></list>
   `,
   directives: [
     ListComponent,
     ProductListItemComponent
   ]
 })
 export class AppComponent { }
```

It doesn't work (of course), because my ListComponent do not receive item component (directive) from app component.

```js
 @Component({
   selector: 'item',
   template: `
     <ul><li *ngFor=...>
       <list-item></list-item>
     </li></ul>
   `
 })
 export class ListComponent { }
```

What should I do, how make it work? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a similar requirement to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: Yes, it is useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the final version, which I build based on [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) (Thank you Gunter!)

The solution is to use a dynamic component as an intermediate between List and List Items of different types.

```js
import {
  Component, 
  ComponentFactory, 
  ComponentRef, 
  Input, 
  ViewContainerRef, 
  ComponentResolver, 
  ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-list-item',
  template: `<div #target></div>`
})
export class DynamicListItem {

  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  @Input() Type: any;
  @Input() Item: any;
  cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;
  private isViewInitialized: boolean = false;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) { }

  updateComponent() {
    if(!this.isViewInitialized) return;
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.Type).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
      this.cmpRef.instance.Item = this.Item;
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.updateComponent();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isViewInitialized = true;
    this.updateComponent();  
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }    
  }

}
```

**[Plunker example RC4](http://plnkr.co/edit/wFVCj0JGXnlYRnrWirOm?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all - does it your real code or copy-paste? Because I see, that almost all of your components have the same selector 'list-item', which is wrong.. it should be uniq.

And the second, about the problem by itself - you should add `ProductListItemComponent` and `PersonListItemComponent` deps right to your `ListComponent` if you want them to render inside list. Like this:

```
import {PersonListItemComponent} from '...';
import {ProductListItemComponent} from '...';

@Component({
 selector: 'list',
 template: `
   <ul><li *ngFor=...>
    <list-item></list-item>
   </li></ul>
 `,
 directives: [
   PersonListItemComponent,
   ProductListItemComponent
 ]
})
export class ListComponent { ...}
```

and for your `AppComponent` you need to add for 'directives' prop only ListComponent

Comment: If I would do like in your example indeed I should give them different selectors, but if I would pass the component dynamically than (I guess) they could be identical.

Comment: Please check my solution. In the final version there is no selectors at all!